# B450M DS3H WIFI doesn't boot up with 16GB DDR4 2666Mhz RAM Stick

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have 32GB (16GBx2) DDR4 2666MHz RAM and I've just purchased the Gigabyte B450M DS3H wifi mobo. When I configured it, the PC didn't boot up with these RAMs. I've tried to install the RAM one by one but nothing works.

However, I've another RAM of 4GB with the same frequency, and when I installed that one 4GB RAM, the PC bootup.

I'm unable to understand why the 4GB or RAM is working fine while the 16GB module with the same frequency not working. I've read the Motherboard configuration and it does support the 2666MHz of RAM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Find out your AMD CPU family architecture; 2. Download the correspondent QVL from https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-1x/support#support-doc; 3. Check if the RAM you have is listed and what configurations are supported.

Comment: Thank you for the link @ChanganAuto. I didn't notice that it has the list of supported RAMs. Sadly, my RAM isn't mentioned in the list, so I must change it. Do you have any suggestions for the RAM for that?